# Orange Data Mining - Pythonw.exe has stopped working - errors

Tags: data-mining, orange

I have installed the complete Orange Data mining windows package.
When starting from the program Icon the Orange Canvas will show up but at some point the error message Pythonw.exe has stopped working will appear

As pointed out in some other posts I started from the command line

```
C:\Python27>python.exe -m Orange.OrangeCanvas.main -l3
```

and get following log - any recommendations what to do?

UPDATE: just found  a log in the C:\Users\nnnn\AppData\Roaming\orange\OrangeCanvasQt4\outputLog.html

```
There were problems importing the following widgets:
 OWC45Tree: c45 is not found
 OWRScript: No module named rpy2.robjects
 OWLinProj3D: No module named OpenGL
 OWNxExplorer3D: No module named OWNxExplorerQt
 OWScatterPlot3D: No module named OpenGL
 OWSphereviz3D: No module named OpenGL
 The following widgets could not be imported and will not be available: OWSphereviz3D, OWScatterPlot3D, OWLinProj3D, OWC45Tree, OWNxExplorer3D.
 The following prototype widgets could not be imported and will not be available: OWRScript.
Unhandled exception of type NameError occured at 20:58:30:
Traceback:
  File: OWWidget.py, line 178 in reportAndFinish
  Code: self.sendReport()
    File: OWQuickSelect.py, line 121 in sendReport
    Code: if self.selectedAttribute and 0 <= self.selectedAttribute[0] <= len(self.attributes) else _("(none)")),
      NameError: global name '_' is not defined 




C:\Python27>python.exe -m Orange.OrangeCanvas.main -l3
Setting up Canvas main window.
'CanvasScene(objectName='', ...)' intitialized.
Setting registry 'None on 'CanvasScene(objectName='', ...)'.
'CanvasScene(objectName='', ...)' cleared.
'CanvasScene(objectName='', ...)' intitialized.
Setting registry 'None on 'CanvasScene(objectName='', ...)'.
Setting scheme '<Orange.OrangeCanvas.scheme.widgetsscheme.WidgetsScheme object at 0x04C12E40>' on 'CanvasScene(objectName='', ...)'
Ignoring 'C:\\Python27\\lib\\site-packages\\Orange\\OrangeWidgets\\Visualize\\OWLinProjGraph.py'.
Ignoring 'C:\\Python27\\lib\\site-packages\\Orange\\OrangeWidgets\\Visualize\\OWParallelGraph.py'.
Ignoring 'C:\\Python27\\lib\\site-packages\\Orange\\OrangeWidgets\\Visualize\\OWPolyvizGraph.py'.
Ignoring 'C:\\Python27\\lib\\site-packages\\Orange\\OrangeWidgets\\Visualize\\OWScatterPlotGraph.py'.
Ignoring 'C:\\Python27\\lib\\site-packages\\Orange\\OrangeWidgets\\Visualize\\OWSieveMultigramGraph.py'.
Ignoring 'C:\\Python27\\lib\\site-packages\\Orange\\OrangeWidgets\\Visualize\\OWSurveyPlotGraph.py'.
Could not import 'Orange.OrangeWidgets.Classify.OWC45Tree'.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\Orange\OrangeCanvas\registry\discovery.py", line 296, in iter_widget_descriptions
    module = asmodule(name)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\Orange\OrangeCanvas\registry\discovery.py", line 557, in asmodule
    return __import__(module, fromlist=[""])
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\Orange\OrangeWidgets\Classify\OWC45Tree.py", line 35, in <module>
    raise ImportError("c45 is not found")
ImportError: c45 is not found
Ignoring 'C:\\Python27\\lib\\site-packages\\Orange\\OrangeWidgets\\Classify\\OWNomogramGraph.py'.
Could not import 'Orange.OrangeWidgets.Prototypes.OWRScript'.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\Orange\OrangeCanvas\registry\discovery.py", line 296, in iter_widget_descriptions
    module = asmodule(name)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\Orange\OrangeCanvas\registry\discovery.py", line 557, in asmodule
    return __import__(module, fromlist=[""])
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\Orange\OrangeWidgets\Prototypes\OWRScript.py", line 12, in <module>
    import Orange.utils.r as r
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\Orange\utils\r.py", line 19, in <module>
    import rpy2.robjects as robjects
ImportError: No module named rpy2.robjects
Ignoring 'C:\\Python27\\lib\\site-packages\\Orange\\OrangeWidgets\\Prototypes\\OWTimeDataVisualizerGraph.py'.
Could not import 'Orange.OrangeWidgets.VisualizeQt.OWLinProj3D'.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\Orange\OrangeCanvas\registry\discovery.py", line 296, in iter_widget_descriptions
    module = asmodule(name)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\Orange\OrangeCanvas\registry\discovery.py", line 557, in asmodule
    return __import__(module, fromlist=[""])
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\Orange\OrangeWidgets\VisualizeQt\OWLinProj3D.py", line 7, in <module>
    from plot.owplot3d import *
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\Orange\OrangeWidgets\plot\owplot3d.py", line 28, in <module>
    from owopenglrenderer import OWOpenGLRenderer
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\Orange\OrangeWidgets\plot\owopenglrenderer.py", line 19, in <module>
    import OpenGL
ImportError: No module named OpenGL
Could not import 'Orange.OrangeWidgets.VisualizeQt.OWLinProj3DPlot'.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\Orange\OrangeCanvas\registry\discovery.py", line 296, in iter_widget_descriptions
    module = asmodule(name)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\Orange\OrangeCanvas\registry\discovery.py", line 557, in asmodule
    return __import__(module, fromlist=[""])
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\Orange\OrangeWidgets\VisualizeQt\OWLinProj3DPlot.py", line 3, in <module>
    from plot.owplot3d import *
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\Orange\OrangeWidgets\plot\owplot3d.py", line 28, in <module>
    from owopenglrenderer import OWOpenGLRenderer
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\Orange\OrangeWidgets\plot\owopenglrenderer.py", line 19, in <module>
    import OpenGL
ImportError: No module named OpenGL
Ignoring 'C:\\Python27\\lib\\site-packages\\Orange\\OrangeWidgets\\VisualizeQt\\OWLinProjGraphQt.py'.
Could not import 'Orange.OrangeWidgets.VisualizeQt.OWNxCanvas3D'.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\Orange\OrangeCanvas\registry\discovery.py", line 296, in iter_widget_descriptions
    module = asmodule(name)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\Orange\OrangeCanvas\registry\discovery.py", line 557, in asmodule
    return __import__(module, fromlist=[""])
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\Orange\OrangeWidgets\VisualizeQt\OWNxCanvas3D.py", line 1, in <module>
    from plot.owplot3d import OWPlot3D, GL_FLOAT, GL_LINES, GL_POINTS, glEnable, GL_PROGRAM_POINT_SIZE
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\Orange\OrangeWidgets\plot\owplot3d.py", line 28, in <module>
    from owopenglrenderer import OWOpenGLRenderer
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\Orange\OrangeWidgets\plot\owopenglrenderer.py", line 19, in <module>
    import OpenGL
ImportError: No module named OpenGL
Could not import 'Orange.OrangeWidgets.VisualizeQt.OWNxExplorer3D'.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\Orange\OrangeCanvas\registry\discovery.py", line 296, in iter_widget_descriptions
    module = asmodule(name)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\Orange\OrangeCanvas\registry\discovery.py", line 557, in asmodule
    return __import__(module, fromlist=[""])
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\Orange\OrangeWidgets\VisualizeQt\OWNxExplorer3D.py", line 9, in <module>
    from OWNxExplorerQt import OWNxExplorerQt
ImportError: No module named OWNxExplorerQt
Ignoring 'C:\\Python27\\lib\\site-packages\\Orange\\OrangeWidgets\\VisualizeQt\\OWParallelGraphQt.py'.
Ignoring 'C:\\Python27\\lib\\site-packages\\Orange\\OrangeWidgets\\VisualizeQt\\OWPolyvizGraphQt.py'.
Could not import 'Orange.OrangeWidgets.VisualizeQt.OWScatterPlot3D'.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\Orange\OrangeCanvas\registry\discovery.py", line 296, in iter_widget_descriptions
    module = asmodule(name)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\Orange\OrangeCanvas\registry\discovery.py", line 557, in asmodule
    return __import__(module, fromlist=[""])
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\Orange\OrangeWidgets\VisualizeQt\OWScatterPlot3D.py", line 10, in <module>
    from plot.owplot3d import *
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\Orange\OrangeWidgets\plot\owplot3d.py", line 28, in <module>
    from owopenglrenderer import OWOpenGLRenderer
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\Orange\OrangeWidgets\plot\owopenglrenderer.py", line 19, in <module>
    import OpenGL
ImportError: No module named OpenGL
Ignoring 'C:\\Python27\\lib\\site-packages\\Orange\\OrangeWidgets\\VisualizeQt\\OWScatterPlotGraphQt.py'.
Could not import 'Orange.OrangeWidgets.VisualizeQt.OWSphereviz3D'.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\Orange\OrangeCanvas\registry\discovery.py", line 296, in iter_widget_descriptions
    module = asmodule(name)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\Orange\OrangeCanvas\registry\discovery.py", line 557, in asmodule
    return __import__(module, fromlist=[""])
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\Orange\OrangeWidgets\VisualizeQt\OWSphereviz3D.py", line 11, in <module>
    from plot.owplot3d import *
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\Orange\OrangeWidgets\plot\owplot3d.py", line 28, in <module>
    from owopenglrenderer import OWOpenGLRenderer
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\Orange\OrangeWidgets\plot\owopenglrenderer.py", line 19, in <module>
    import OpenGL
ImportError: No module named OpenGL
Setting registry '<Orange.OrangeCanvas.registry.qt.QtWidgetRegistry object at 0x04CBAF60> on 'CanvasScene(objectName='', ...)'.
Created <class 'Orange.OrangeCanvas.help.provider.IntersphinxHelpProvider'> provider for Orange 2.7.8
```